# How can I embed a JUPYTERHUB into iframe?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jupyterhub

I tried all solutions on github, but none of these works

this is my current [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glduf.png).

`<iframe src="http://xxx:8000/"></iframe>`

**Update**

enter code here

It's jupyterhub config file.

```
`
c.Authenticator.whitelist = {'user'}
c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'admin'}
c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': 'frame-ancestors self http://localhost:8080',
    }
}
c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {'headers': {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOW-FROM http://localhost:8080/'}}
`
```

It's jupyter notebook config file

```
`
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors http://localhost:8080/ 'self' "
    }
}
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {'headers': {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOW- FROM http://localhost:8080/'}}
`
```

Comment: Don't post a link; place all your relevant code in the question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thank you! Actually there r no codes.. All configs and iframe code r listed now.